# Lisp : how to use recursion to defun a function that given a nonnegative integer N, produce the list of all integers from 1 up to and including N?

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, lisp, common-lisp

write a function in lisp called number(N) that you have to use a nonnegative integer N, and produce the list of all integers from 1 up to and including N.

```
(defun numbers (N)  
  (if (<= N 0)
      nil
      (cons N nil)
      (numbers (- N 1)))
```

I checked some questions, but most of them use loop and range, but this question doesn't allowed me to do this, so I have to use recursion instead:

here is my code, but this code keeps giving me warning:

```
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable N is defined but never used.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 ERROR condition
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
```

I think my algorithm is correct ,but because I am new to lisp, I still don't know how to write the function properly. It is grateful if anyone could gave me any help.

Comment: Which lisp interpreter are you using? I don't think `if` accepts four arguments.

Comment: @ymonad uh...I am not sure which interpreter I am using(it is from school's computer)...and if i cannot use if statement, what else I am able to use ?

Comment: Using `if` statement is OK. Just that it can only pass three argument: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_if.htm .

Comment: So you have to pass `(cons N (numbers (- N 1)))` instead of `(cons N nil) (numbers (- N 1))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to think about this is to think about what the algorithm should be:

> To compute the numbers from `1` to `n`:
>
> - if `n` is less than `1` then there are no numbers, so this is the empty list;
> - otherwise we want a list which looks like `(... n)`, where `...` is all the numbers from `1` to `n-1`.

Note that we want the numbers in forward order: this is going to be critical.

Doing this is slightly difficult in Lisp because we want the number to be at the *end* of the list, and access to the ends of lists is hard.

Here is the start of a version which builds the list backwards (so this is not the right answer).

```
(defun numbers (n)
  (if (< n 1)
      '()                               ;the empty list
    ;; n 1 or more, so build a list which is (n . ...)
    (cons n <some function involving n>)))
```

Well, OK, what function should we call recursively?  Do we have a function which returns the list we want?  Well, yes: it's `numbers`, with an argument which is one less than `n`!

```
(defun numbers (n)
  (if (< n 1)
      '()
    (cons n (numbers (- n 1)))))
```

And this function works.  But it gets the wrong answer: the list is backwards:

```
> (numbers 10)
(10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
```

There are two fixes to this problem: the first is to build the list forwards, using `append`.  This version looks like this (remember `append` wants to append two lists: it doesn't append an element to the end of a list):

```
(defun numbers (n)
  (if (< n 1)
      '()
    (append (numbers (- n 1)) (list n))))
```

This gets the right answer:

```
> (numbers 10)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

but it's a *terrible* answer: `append` has to walk all the way down the list (lists in Lisp are chains of conses: there is no fast access to the end of a list), copying it as it goes, to append the new element.  So this has absolutely terrible space & time complexity.  Programs written like this are why 'Lisp is slow'.

A better approach is to build the list backwards and then reverse it.

```
(defun numbers (n)
  (reverse (numbers-backwards n)))

(defun numbers-backwards (n)
  (if (< n 1)
      '()
    (cons n (numbers-backwards (- n 1)))))
```

The problem with this, from the homework perspective, might be that using `reverse` is not allowed.  That's OK, we can write it, recursively.  The implementation is slightly fiddly, but this is going to help us below.

```
(defun reverse-list (l)
  ;; in real life reverse-list-accumulator would be a local function
  (reverse-list-accumulator l '()))

(defun reverse-list-accumulator (l accum)
  (if (null l)
      accum
    (reverse-list-accumulator (rest l) (cons (first l) accum))))
```

The way this works is that `reverse-list` calls this auxiliary function with an extra argument.  The auxiliary function then checks the list, and if it's not empty it calls itself with the tail of the list and the head of the list consed onto the auxiliary argument.  If it is empty, it returns the auxiliary argument.  It's a little subtle but you can see that this in fact reverses the list.

So now we can write our function using only recursive functions we wrote:

```
(defun numbers (n)
  (reverse-list (numbers-backwards n)))
```

But now there should be a moment of inspiration: *why are we doing this whole
build-it-backwards-and-reverse-it thing*?  Why don't we just make `numbers` do the accumulator trick itself!  Well, we can do that:

```
(defun numbers (n)
  (numbers-accumulator n '()))

(defun numbers-accumulator (n accum)
  (if (< n 1)
      accum
    (numbers-accumulator (- n 1) (cons n accum))))
```

And now we don't need to reverse the list, and for added value our
function is 'tail recursive' and will generally be compiled much more
efficiently.

---

A real-life version of `numbers` might look more like this, using a local function:

```
(defun numbers (n)
  (labels ((numbers-accumulator (m accum)
             (if (< m 1)
                 accum
               (numbers-accumulator (- m 1) (cons m accum)))))
    (numbers-accumulator n '())))
```

Here is a comparison between the version of `numbers` using `append` and the above function, on an argument small enough that the `append` version does not overflow the stack.

```
> (time (progn (numbers/append 2000) (values)))
Timing the evaluation of (progn (numbers/append 2000) (values))

User time    =        0.024
System time  =        0.001
Elapsed time =        0.017
Allocation   = 32176304 bytes
97 Page faults

> (time (progn (numbers 2000) (values)))
Timing the evaluation of (progn (numbers 2000) (values))

User time    =        0.000
System time  =        0.000
Elapsed time =        0.001
Allocation   = 32000 bytes
0 Page faults
```

You can see how terrible the `append` version is, and how good the other one is: this is a 64-bit Lisp, and conses are two words or 16 bytes: it has allocated precisely 2000 cons cells which is the minimum it could do.

Answer (score 6):

**IF has generally a common syntax, but there are exceptions**

Generally in Lisps like Common Lisp the `if` operator allows the following syntax:

```
IF test-form then-form [else-form]
```

This means that in Lisp usually zero or one *else-form* are allowed. An example is `if` in Common Lisp.

In Emacs Lisp multiple *else-forms* are allowed. Emacs Lisp has the following syntax:

```
IF test-form then-form else-form*
```

This means that in Emacs Lisp zero or more *else-forms* are allowed.

**Thus**: it's important to mention which language&dialect you are actually using.

**Your code**

a) Let's assume that you use Common Lisp with its *IF* syntax.

Your code:

```
(defun numbers (N)  
  (if (<= N 0)
      nil
    (cons N nil)
    (numbers (- N 1)))
```

Your code has the problem, that there are more than one else clauses. You need to write a version which has a single else clause.

b) Let's assume that you use Emacs Lisp with its *IF* syntax with multiple else forms.

Your code:

```
(defun numbers (N)  
  (if (<= N 0)
      nil
    (cons N nil)
    (numbers (- N 1)))
```

Here the `(cons N nil)` form is allowed, but has no effect. Its return value is not used and it has no side effect. You could delete it and it would make no difference. Again: you would need how to combine its effect with the form `(numbers (- N 1))`.

**Syntax error: missing closing parenthesis**

There is another problem in your code. The s-expressions are not complete -> a closing parenthesis is missing:

```
(defun numbers (N)  
  (if (<= N 0)
      nil
      (cons N nil)
      (numbers (- N 1)))
```

As you can see a closing parenthesis is missing at the end.

Thus your code can not be read by Lisp.

There are two ways one generally can avoid this problem:

- count the parentheses and set them accordingly
- use the editor to count the parentheses

Most people prefer the latter.